# Summing the lowest 5 cells out of 7 cells (which are part of a larger set of cells)

Tags: google-sheets, sum

I would like to add the 5 lowest scores (out of 7) only from the purple fields (in my image below).

If there are no numbers in `B1`, `D1`, `F1`, `H1`, `J1`, `L1`, or `N1`, the formula

`=SUM(A1:M1)-SUM(LARGE(A1:M1,1),LARGE(A1:M1,2))`

would work and it would give me the right answer (which in this case would be  **-14**).

I just don't know how to select certain cells so that it sums only the lowest 5 numbers.

[image]

Comment: Which do you want as the approaches are different: Excel or Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: Please include the relevant code including your formula within your question, if you have questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What have you tried to do? Just posting a screenshot of your setup does not qualify as making an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Google Sheets:

This is the formula that should work for you in Google Sheets:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF(ISODD(COLUMN($A$1:$N$1)),$A$1:$N$1,""),{1,2,3,4,5})))`

#### Microsoft Excel:

To use this formula in Microsoft Excel, you'll need to modify it to this (committing it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

`=SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF(ISODD(COLUMN($A$1:$N$1)),$A$1:$N$1,""),{1,2,3,4,5}))`

---

What both formulas are essentially doing is determining if your column is an even or odd column. When it's odd, you get the number from your range - `$A$1:$N$1` - and when it's even, you get `""`. By wrapping that up in a `SMALL` function and using an array for the `k` argument (`{1,2,3,4,5}`) you are essentially asking for the five smallest values. Finally, by using `SUMPRODUCT` with only one argument, you're going to get the sum of your lowest five numbers from your odd columns only.

Comment: My original spreadsheet is for a golf tournament. I'm replacing 0 to E. The formula works when the whole field is numbers but when someone has 0, because it turns to E, the formula stop working. Is there anyway I can add SUBSTITUTE to the formula and replace E to 0?  =ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF(ISODD(COLUMN($A$1:$N$1)),$A$1:$N$1,""),{1,2,3,4,5})))

Comment: This formula works fine if the 7 cells are all filled with numbers but If the 5 of the 7 cells have 0 and other 2 cells have numbers like 3 and 6, the formula gives me 9 instead of 0 (needs to add 5 lowest numbers out of 7 numbers). =SUM(SORTN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:M1,ISODD(COLUMN(A1:M1)),ISNUMBER(A1:M1))),5,,1,1))

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me but my knowledge of Spreadsheet is very little and things aren't working. I'm sure its a minor mistake but I can't spot it. Is it ok if I send you the link to my Spreadsheet and someone take a look and see what's wrong?

Comment: @R.K., when I change the `0`'s in the data set to `E` (no quotes or anything else), the formula still works as expected. Can you possibly update your original question with what your data set now looks like along with how the formula is behaving? Right now I'm unable to replicate your issue.